# How to update a collection with linq if no record exist and if exist update it's property

Tags: c#, linq

I am to add an object to collection but i want to know how can i update it, if record exist and if norecord exist.

i am to work on this.

```
public void AssignProductSetting(CategoryType catType, int catId, int freeCount)
        {
            this.CustomSettings.Add(new ProductCustomization()
            {
                CategoryID = catId,
                CustomizationType = catType,
                DefaultFreeCount = freeCount,
                ProductID = this.ProductID
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(CustomeSettings == null) CustomerSettings = 
                                    new Collection<ProductCustomization>();

var cat = CustomSettings.FirstOrDefault(r=>r.CategoryId == catID && 
                                           r.CustomizationType == catType);
if(cat!=null)
{ 
     cat.DefaultFreeCount = freeCount;
     cat.ProductID = this.ProductID;
}
else
{
     this.CustomSettings.Add(new ProductCustomization()
        {
            CategoryID = catId,
            CustomizationType = catType,
            DefaultFreeCount = freeCount,
            ProductID = this.ProductID
        });
 }
```

Comment: if i need to check 2 condition in it then what like catd and catype both need to check.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(this.CustomSettings.Any(x=>x.CategoryID == catId))
{
  //Update
} 
else
{
  //Add
}
```